# Migrate a Win 2008 R2 Domain - Win 2016 to a new server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2016

I've a server with win 2008 R2 64 Bit and 5 clients win10 pro
I bought a new server and i want to install Windows 2016
What are the best steps to migrate the existing domain without having to modify the clients

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Setup AD onto Windows Server 2016.
2. Join the existing domain.
3. Sync the data.
4. Remove 2008 server from the domain.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1947811-adding-windows-2016-as-domain-controller-to-2008-r2-domain